# Prove: There exists an even integer $n$ that can be written in two different ways as a sum of two distinct primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am working on this problem,

> Prove: There exists an even integer $n$ that can be written in two different ways
> as a sum of two distinct primes.

I know:

> $3+13=11+5=16$
>
> $11+13=7+17=24$
>
> $23+7=11+19=30$

I don't see any information to help me do the question from my examples, can anyone give me a hint or suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have already proved the statement. You proved the "existence of an even integer $n$ ..." by giving an example, e.g. $n = 14$

Comment: Perhaps he would like a way to show precisely which even integers are able to be broken down in this manner?

Answer (score 6):

You had already done what was required. The question asks you to prove that there exists an even integer which can be written in two different ways as the sum of two distinct primes. So, your mission is to find such one. Any of your examples would suffice as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You already did it. The exercise asks you to show that one such even integer exists, and you have demonstrated that at least three such even integers exist. Moreover, 16 is the smallest even integer that can be written in two different ways as a sum of two distinct primes; 18, 20, 22 also have two such representations, and for 24 you can also do $19 + 5$.

If the exercise instead asked you to prove that infinitely many even integers have this property, it would be considerably more difficult: Christian Goldbach might jump out of his grave if you managed to prove it.

Comment: Proving that infinitely many evens can be done this way is not Goldbach's conjecture

Comment: @Ross But he would still be very interested in that result.